# Add text to automatic labels and textboxes vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

The following code creates/formats labels and textboxes to a groupbox.

My problem is that i want to change the textbox text to `1` and `0` periodically ( like intercalated ), and i have no idea how to.

```
Private Sub ResizeData()
    ' Create as many textboxes as fit into window
    grpData.Controls.Clear()
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 10
    Dim z As Integer = 20
    While y < grpData.Size.Width - 100
        labData = New Label()
        grpData.Controls.Add(labData)
        labData.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(30, 20)
        labData.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y, z)


        labData.Text = Convert.ToString(x + 1)

        txtData = New TextBox()
        grpData.Controls.Add(txtData)
        txtData.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 20)
        txtData.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y + 30, z)
        txtData.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Right
        txtData.Tag = x


        x += 1
        z = z + txtData.Size.Height + 5
        If z > grpData.Size.Height - 40 Then
            y = y + 100
            z = 20
        End If
    End While

End Sub
```

i need something like this:

```
txtData1.text="1"
txtData2.text="0"
txtData3.text="1"
txtData4.text="0"
```

...and so on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub ResizeData()
    ' Create as many textboxes as fit into window
    grpData.Controls.Clear()
    Dim a As Integer = 1
    Dim x As Integer = 1
    Dim y As Integer = 10
    Dim z As Integer = 20
    While y < grpData.Size.Width - 100

        Dim labData As New Label()
        grpData.Controls.Add(labData)
        labData.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(30, 20)
        labData.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y, z)


        labData.Text = Convert.ToString(a)


        Dim txtData As New TextBox()
        grpData.Controls.Add(txtData)
        txtData.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 20)
        txtData.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(y + 30, z)
        txtData.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Right
        txtData.Tag = x
        txtData.Text = x

        a += 1
        If x = 1 Then
            x = 0
        ElseIf x = 0 Then
            x = 1
        End If

        z = z + txtData.Size.Height + 5
        If z > grpData.Size.Height - 40 Then
            y = y + 100
            z = 20
        End If
    End While

End Sub
```

To give only the first 2 textboxes a value '1', use the same code above with these 3 lines modified:

```
 Dim txtData As New TextBox() With {.Name = "txt" & a}
 txtData.Text = 0
 If txtData.Name = "txt1" Or txtData.Name = "txt2" Then txtData.Text = 1 'add this line just below the above one
```

Comment: I've tested ur code and it works.. with the labels ! I want that text in the textboxes ( txtData.text ) . Thank you !

Comment: Code above has been updated: labels increment, textboxes swith between 1 and 0

Comment: pretty nice ! Thank you !

Comment: btw, just for curiosity, what if i wanted just the first two textboxes to have the text "1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a boolean would work. Not the cleaner way but it should work

Where you dim everything:

```
Dim even as boolean
```

And after all the property changes of the txtData:

```
if even then
    txtData.Text=1
else
    txtData.Text=0
end if
even= not even
```

Comment: nope. didn't work . It only changes the value of the last textbox.